# How to override English labels inserted by Sphinx

Tags: python, pdf, internationalization, pdf-generation, python-sphinx

I use the [Sphinx Python documentation generator](https://www.sphinx-doc.org). Creating PDF documents is very easy and simple, but I have one problem.

All generated PDF documents have *English* words like "chapter", "release", and "part".

How can I override these English labels in another language, or remove them completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sphinx generates LaTeX files, and then uses LaTeX to generate the PDF. So yes, you can, but it typically involves learning LaTeX and changing the LaTeX macros. I did a quick search and couldn't find any place where the "Chapter" was defined, so it's probably defined in the Bjarne chapter heading style (which is the default), which means you need to find that definition and see of you can override it, or make a new definition.

LaTeX is *big*, so take a deep breath. But it's definitely possible. :)

Comment: Thank you for answer and your research. I think it is good moment for me to learn LaTeX:).

Comment: It is also possible to generate PDFs with rst2pdf. http://techtonik.rainforce.org/2010/05/sphinx-pdf-with-rst2pdf.html

Comment: Actually it isn't difficult at all, see my answer below. Apart from installing latex and the required language packages (babel) you only have to make a small configuration change to conf.py.

Answer (score 11):

In your `conf.py`, there is the following paragraph (around line 57 in a `conf.py` created by `sphinx-quickstart`):

```
# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#language = None
```

In my case, I changed it to:

```
language = nl      # bug!
```

Which of course should be:

```
language = 'nl'    # don't forget the quotes :-)
```

This will work for all Sphinx output; in my case, I only checked the html and latex output. On the Spinx website, there is [list of supported languages](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html?highlight=supported%20languages#confval-language).

Comment: It could be that you should install some language packages for you latex distribution. Better ask that question on http://tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note that I didn't have to do that. I use MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows. Last time I ran it on Linux (last year; Ubuntu 9.04) I had to install some language packages, which was quite straightforward.